# rake db:seed aborted (uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enumerize

I got a new project, and running the seed files (rake db:seed) gives me this error:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Type
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/enumerize-2.1.2/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:69:in `<module:ActiveRecordSupport>'
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/enumerize-2.1.2/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:2:in `<module:Enumerize>'
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/enumerize-2.1.2/lib/enumerize/activerecord.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/enumerize-2.1.2/lib/enumerize.rb:35:in `extended'
/Users/mekto/web/redhat/rhcsa/sherpa/app/models/task.rb:55:in `extend'
/Users/mekto/web/redhat/rhcsa/sherpa/app/models/task.rb:55:in `<class:Task>'
/Users/mekto/web/redhat/rhcsa/sherpa/app/models/task.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mekto/web/redhat/rhcsa/sherpa/db/seeds.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:347:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/mekto/.gem/ruby/2.1.4/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

And from those logs the problem seems to be in the task.rb file and the enumerize module.

The code from the task.rb file that it complains about:

```
 extend Enumerize
 enumerize :track, in: {:learning => 0, :action => 1}, default: :learning

 acts_as_list scope: :step
 has_paper_trail ignore: [:updated_at, :impressions_count]
 is_impressionable :counter_cache => true
```

Tnx,
Tom

Comment: which ORM are you using? is it `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: Yes its Active Record...

Comment: did you try bundle install; sometimes there is no gem in your system

Comment: yes I did, that was the first thing I tried, and I also checked for it: gem list | grep enumerize / enumerize (2.1.2)

Comment: does it help?
 https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/533#issuecomment-101849372

Comment: no, the problem persists!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148122/discussion-between-illusionist-and-tomislav-mikulin).

Comment: I think you need to downgrade enumerize version to `~1.1.x`